# Bkav antivirus tool is showing malware in my app how can i find out what is the malware in my app.

Tags: android, malware, antivirus

I have created one android app,for the virus check purpose i upload it in virustotal site it is show as Bkav is detect a malware in my app.Which is **Android.Malware.CeV1.773C** i don't know what this mean i try to search in google and SO also but i didn't get any info regarding this malware.Is anyone knows what is this exactly.If any one knows answer please post it,it will help me a lot.

**Note:** To cross verify i upload a sample app which only contain hello world,for this app also Bkav is showing malware.

I want to know is there any reason i am getting this malware.I want information about this at least why it is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

In your Hello World app, did you keep some libs in the build.gradle file? It makes me think to a false positive due to a library. I had a similar issue with the guava library.
You should send your Hello World apk to Bkav so that they fix this false positive. There are some email addresses on their contact-us page where you can send this apk for a finer analysis.

Comment: in hello world app nothing is there it is just basic app,gradle file is contain only default support library.I just create an app in studio and build signed apk and check for virus in bkav it is showing it is containing virus.

Comment: I tested an apk few hours ago and got the same issue. So i wrote to them. I did not get an answer, but I tested the same file few minutes ago and virustotal no longer shows this alert. Is it also solved for you?

Comment: yes from yesterday afternoon they updated in virus total from on wards virus is not coming i checked for my apps.I think it is false positive report even i am also reported about this virus to them yesterday morning.